# How do I make a custom collectionview cell visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I can't seem to make my custom collectionView Cell visible. I know that the CollectionView shows up because I changed the background color on the attributes inspector, but the custom cell is not showing up. I set the constraints in the attributes inspector and have a horizontal stack view under the image.

I followed the direction from a Udemy course exactly but it doesn't seem to work. This is how I have configured the cell to look:

[image]

The code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ListVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var productsCollection: UICollectionView!

    private(set) public var products = [Product]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        productsCollection.dataSource = self
        productsCollection.delegate = self
    }

    func initProducts(Product: Product) {
        products = DataService.instance.getGroceryOptions()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return products.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductCell {
            let product = products[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateViews(product: product)
            return cell
        }
        return ProductCell()

    }
}
```

Here is the ProductCell implementation:

```
class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var calCount: UILabel!

    func updateViews(product: Product){
        itemImage.image = UIImage(named: product.imageName)
        productName.text = product.title
        calCount.text = product.cal
        productPrice.text = product.price
    }

}
```

Here is the DataService implementation:

```
class DataService {
    static let instance = DataService()

    private let item = [
        Product(title: "Eggs", price: "4.94", imageName: "eggs.jpeg", cal: "340"),
    ]

    private let Groceries = [Product]()

    func getGroceryOptions() -> [Product] {
        return Products
    }
}
```

Here is the Product implementation:

```
struct Product {
    private(set) public var title: String
    private(set) public var price: String
    private(set) public var imageName: String
    private(set) public var cal: String

    init(title: String, price: String, imageName: String, cal: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.price = price
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.cal = cal
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `getGroceryOptions` do? make sure that there are data to be shown

Comment: I would start by adding some print statements or debugger breakpoints to get an image of what code is actually being executed.

Comment: it seems that products  array is not initialized

Comment: Should `return Products` actually be `return item`?

Comment: @PhillipMills This is my first attempt at an app so thanks for reminding me about using print statements, and no it should return item, I forgot to edit in all scopes.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your `initProducts` method is not called anywhere in the code.

2) You have to call `collectionView.reloadData()` after you update your data source. Which means, you have to call this method after updating `products` property.

3) Also, as other people in their answers mentioned, seems that your `getGroceryOptions()` method should actually return `items` instead of `Products` (what's that, btw?).

4) Please, follow swift style guide for writing your code. It will be easier for you to distinguish classes/struct from variables. You can learn more about it [here](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) and also [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide).

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I used collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath]) instead of collectionView.reloadData() since that wasn't working. Is this another way to get the same result? I changed the method from returning Products to items but must have forgotten to change it, I think I should have used edit in all scopes. I'm going to pay way more attention to the style guide and the github style guide moving forward, thanks

Comment: `collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` should be used, when you updated few models and need to update related cells in your collection view. But when you changing the whole array, which your datasource is using, then `collectionView.reloadData()` is your choice :)
You can look in documentation to find more information about these methods

Answer (score 0):

Your `initProducts` method is not called. Because of this `products` array stays empty and you see no cells in your collection.

You should call `initProducts` (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`) to fill `products` array with elements which will be shown in your collection.

Also consider removing parameters from this function (you're not using parameter within this method, so you don't need it there). It should look like:

```
func initProducts() {
        products = DataService.instance.getGroceryOptions()
}
```

Plus you should correct `getGroceryOptions` method. It should return `item` as was pointed out in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` section that goes before the other `collectionView` functions?

Take a look at this example:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Absence of this method’s implementation results in one single sections (in accordance with documentation). In this case that’s ok.